# nuxt3 I cannot receive the changed value from the parent component in the child component

Tags: nuxt3

I have a question and I’m posting it here. The memberships changed through useAsyncData in the parent component is not being changed in the child component.

Parent Component

```
<ExpiredMembershipList :memberships=“memberships” v-model:search-form=“searchForm” />

<script setup lang=“ts”> 
const searchForm = ref({ caIdx: null, sex: null, age: null, reRegYn: null, startDate: null, endDate: null, srchWord: null, });
// Two methods I tried, first
const memberships: ComputedRef = computed(() => {
  return membershipSub.value?.data.memberships.content;
})
// Two methods I tried, second 
const memberships = ref([]);

watchDebounced(
  searchForm,
  () => {
    membershipRefresh();
  },
  { debounce: 500, maxWait: 1000, deep: true },
)

const { data: membershipSub, refresh: membershipRefresh } = await useAsyncData(
  "membership",
  () => ($fetch as any)(`${apiBase}/api/v1/owner/membership/expire/list`, {
    query: {
      gymIdx: gymIdx
      , ...searchForm.value
    },
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      Authorization: "Bearer " + token.value,
    },
    onResponse({ request, response, options }) {
      // Two methods I tried, second 
      memberships.value = [...response._data.data.memberships.content]
    },
    onResponseError({ request, response, options }) {
      alert(response._data.message);
    }
  })
);
```

Child Component

```
<template>
{{memberships}} // I want memberships changed.
  <input v-model="searchForm.srchWord">
  <input v-model="searchForm.reRegYn">

</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
definePageMeta({
  layout: "default",
});
const props = defineProps({
  memberships: {
    type: Object,
    required: true,
  },
  searchForm: {
    type: Object,
    required: true,
  },
})
const emit = defineEmits(["update:searchForm"]);
onMounted(() => {
  watch(searchForm, (newVal) => {
    emit("update:searchForm", newVal);
  });
});
const memberships = ref(props.memberships);
const searchForm = ref(props.searchForm);
</script>
```

How do I view the values ​​changed through API calls in the parent component and the values ​​changed normally in the child component?